# Difficulty in understanding what command to write to give me the value of an intent based on my values in an array

Tags: java, eclipse

I have this problem with my code.

I would like the intent return me the value of the array.

If someone Can help me I attach my code here:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include your code as text, rather than as screenshots

Comment: There's a reason it blocked you from spamming the question with pictures. Code should be posted as text.

Comment: Code as screenshots is hard to read. Two screenshots show the same and the most important class is missing. Could you please replace the screenshots with the code of all four classes (in the editor you can select the code and use the `{ }` button to format it as code snippet).

Comment: thanks for your attention .. sorry for the wrong way, so i have expressed my domnda .. i opened a new question, if you can give us a look i would be grateful .. in this new question, i think it will be easier reading the problem I started talking to you !